# Match decimal numbers from nth column in regex

Tags: regex, pcre

I need to match column with P&L in Perl code. Its percentage profit of roundtrip. Can be negative or positive. Number can be -5.12 or 1005.12.

```
2018-03-15 16:38:28 (DEBUG):    current trend duration:   6
2018-03-15 16:38:28 (INFO): 
2018-03-15 16:38:28 (INFO): (ROUNDTRIP) REPORT:
2018-03-15 16:38:28 (INFO): (ROUNDTRIP) entry date (UTC)    exit date (UTC)     exposed duration    P&L     profit
2018-03-15 16:38:28 (INFO): (ROUNDTRIP) 2018-03-10 14:00    2018-03-10 15:10    an hour             -0.00   -0.01
2018-03-15 16:38:28 (INFO): (ROUNDTRIP) 2018-03-10 17:50    2018-03-10 23:00    5 hours             -0.30   -7.72
2018-03-15 16:38:28 (INFO): (ROUNDTRIP) 2018-03-11 02:10    2018-03-11 03:30    an hour             120.06  1.58
2018-03-15 16:38:28 (INFO): (ROUNDTRIP) 2018-03-12 15:40    2018-03-12 22:00    6 hours             -0.15   -4.05
2018-03-15 16:38:28 (INFO): (ROUNDTRIP) 2018-03-13 09:10    2018-03-13 10:10    an hour             0.00    0.13
2018-03-15 16:38:28 (INFO): (ROUNDTRIP) 2018-03-13 12:20    2018-03-13 13:30    an hour             -120.01 -0.36
2018-03-15 16:38:28 (INFO): (ROUNDTRIP) 2018-03-13 21:00    2018-03-13 22:20    an hour             0.06    1.75
2018-03-15 16:38:28 (INFO): 
2018-03-15 16:38:28 (INFO): (PROFIT REPORT) start time:          2018-03-10 00:00:00
```

For example match is:

```
-0.00
-0.30
120.06
-0.15
0.00 
-120.01
0.06
```

How do it with PCRE Regex?

Comment: Why did you tag it as `pcre`? What regex language/tool are you using?

Comment: Im using Perl script code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this perl's regex :

```
ROUNDTRIP\)\s+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*?\K-?\d+\.\d+
```

Exemple whith [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) in [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) mode :

```
$ grep -oP 'ROUNDTRIP\)\s+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*?\K-?\d+\.\d+' file
-0.00
-0.30
120.06
-0.15
0.00
-120.01
0.06
```

Comment: I need negative numbers too.

Comment: my @words2 = $words =~ /ROUNDTRIP\)\s+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*?\K-?\d+\.\d+/g;

Answer (score 0):

It can be very easily done using `awk` **without any regex**:

```
awk 'NF>10 && $11+0 == $11{print $11}' file
```

```
-0.00
-0.30
120.06
-0.15
0.00
-120.01
0.06
```

**Details:**

- Condition `NF>10 && $11+0 == $11` checks if there are more than 10 fields in a row and also makes sure 11th field is numeric
- `{print $11}` prints 11th field of each record

---

If you are looking for `perl` script then here is equivalent `perl` command:

```
perl -alne 'print $F[11] if $F[11] =~ /^-?\d*\.?\d+$/' file
```

```
-0.01
-7.72
1.58
-4.05
0.13
-0.36
1.75
```

---

**perl code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @words;
while(<>)  {
   @words = split(" ");
   if (scalar @words > 10 && $words[11] =~ /^-?\d*\.?\d+$/) {
      print $words[11] . "\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I dont understand You correctly. Looking like have not ended loop when I try this way: my @words = q(2018-03-15 16:38:28 (INFO): (ROUNDTRIP) REPORT: (...)

Comment: Edit your question and provide code that you are using.